# Integrating from Spring security to Spring reactive security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-cloud

I have a Java project who is using spring security and spring cloud routing.

as to my understanding spring cloud routing works with spring reactive security which is a bit different in her authentication managers and providers, and I want to know how can I integrate from an existing spring security configurations to reactive security.

This is my application regular security:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ApplicationConfig {

    private final IUserProxy userProxy;


    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return details -> {
            String[] userDetails = details.split("/");
            String serviceProvider = userDetails[0];
            String username = userDetails[1];

            return userProxy.getUserByUsernameAndServiceProviderName(username, serviceProvider);
        };
    }
    
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        
        return authenticationProvider;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecretGenerator secretGenerator(){
        return new DefaultSecretGenerator();
    }

    @Bean
    public QrGenerator qrGenerator(){
        return new ZxingPngQrGenerator();
    }

    @Bean
    public CodeVerifier codeVerifier(){
        CodeGenerator codeGenerator = new DefaultCodeGenerator();
        TimeProvider timeProvider = new SystemTimeProvider();

        return new DefaultCodeVerifier(codeGenerator, timeProvider);
    }
}
```

and this is my security filter chain:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    
    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter;
    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf()
        .disable()
        .authorizeHttpRequests()
        .requestMatchers("/mng164/auth/**")
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
        .addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        
        return http.build();
    }

}
```

furthermore, is there a way to turn off the security config in my gateway application and just use this one instead of making the integration?

I tried applying the same security configurations to my gateway application, but spring reacted about bean conflicts. one bean from spring-reactive-security and one from spring-security